# Ways to characterize supersingular primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, elliptic-curves, characteristic-p

I've read the definition, and it basically says p is a **supersingular prime** iff 
the fundamental domain of a group generated by \Gamma(p) and a matrix ((0, 1), (-p, 0)) is rational.

And there's a finite list of those, so it's kind of stupid to try to characterize a finite set.

But, anyway, what is the *deep meaning* of supersingular primes? What are different ways to characterize them?

This question actually arose when I posted a different question about one of the characterizations, [the one related to Monster finite group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1247/mystery-of-the-monster). I hope to collect all possible answers from number theory here.

Comment: Duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55/supersingular-elliptic-curves/399#399, though I don't think anyone mentions the congruence subgroup POV.

Comment: Ok, I have to face the fact that I am very ignorant person. But how is the supersingular prime and a supersingular elliptic curve related?

Comment: Looking now at your moonshine question I realize I jumped the gun and that these are probably different notions.

Answer (score 7):

Supersingular primes are those primes p for which all supersingular elliptic curves over an algebraic closure of F<sub>p</sub> have j-invariant in F<sub>p</sub>.  There is a theorem of Deuring that implies the j-invariant always lies in F<sub>p<sup>2</sup></sub> for any prime p, so supersingular primes form a rather distinguished class.  From the standpoint of probabilistic heuristics, you should expect these primes to be rather small, since there are exactly (p-1)/24 supersingular elliptic curves over an algebraic closure of F<sub>p</sub>, weighted by automorphisms.