# What does "supersingular" mean?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, characteristic-p

Are **supersingular primes** and **supersingular elliptic curves** related?

(this was essentially a subquestion in [my earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1249/ways-to-characterize-supersingular-primes), but still looks sufficiently different to me to deserve a separate post)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let F be the finite field with p elements.

A supersingular elliptic curve is an elliptic curve E/F with the property that the endomorphism ring (ring of homomorphisms from E to E)  of E over the algebraic closure of F_p is has rank 4 as a Z-module.

It is a theorem that End(E/F) has rank 2 or rank 4 (and that in the former case, End(E/F) is isomorphic to an order in an imaginary quadratic number ring whereas in the latter case, End(E/F) is isomorphic to an order in a quaternion algebra over Q). Hence, a supersingular elliptic curve over F_p can be thought of as an elliptic curve over F with a "big" endomorphism ring.

It is a theorem that another characterization supersingular elliptic curves is that E/F is supersingular is if and only if the number of points on E/F is exactly p + 1 (edit: for p > 3, see Voloch's comment below).

I believe that the etymology of the term "supersingular" is as follows: if you start with an elliptic curve E/Q over Q, for all but finitely many primes p, reduction (mod p) gives an elliptic curve E/F. For a generic E/Q (specifically, one without "complex multiplication") then the set of primes such that reduction (mod p) turns E/Q into a supersingular E/F has asymptotic density 0. Such primes are called "supersingular primes for E/Q" - supersingular refers to "really unusual." The reductions for such primes are then called supersingular elliptic curves over F. I'm pretty sure that every elliptic curve over F is a (mod p) reduction of an elliptic curve over Q so that all supersingular elliptic curves arise in this way.

I'll remark (following Silverman) that a supersingular elliptic curve over F is not "singular" in the sense of algebraic geometry - by definition all elliptic curves are nonsingular.

I do not know much about supersingular primes in the context of monstrous moonshine. According to Wikipedia, a supersingular prime is a prime that divides the order of the monster group; and there are 15 such primes. Given E/Q, by a theorem of Elkies there will be infinitely many super singular primes p for E/Q. So it's difficult to imagine how the list of 15 supersingular (with respect to moonshine) primes could emerge from the notion of "supersingular elliptic curve." I imagine that the etymology of the term "supersingular" in the context of moonshine is again that that supersingular primes are special - but that they special in a completely different way from the supersingular primes for a elliptic curve over Q.

Comment: "E/F is supersingular is if and only if the number of points on E/F is exactly p + 1." This is only true for p prime, p > 3. The correct statement is that the curve is supersingular if and only if the number of points is p+1-t and t is divisible by p. Since $|t| \le 2\sqrt{p}$, it follows that t = 0, when p is prime, p > 3.

Comment: I don't know the actual etymology but I have thought it is as follows: In the (very) old days a singular (in the sense of special) modulus was the $j$-invariant of a lattice in $\mathbb C$ with complex multiplication. From the point of view of elliptic curves this corresponds to the $j$-invariants of complex elliptic curves with endomorphism ring larger than $\mathbb Z$. In positive characteristic there are some elliptic curves with larger endomorphism rings than complex curves can have, they are clearly even more special, hence supersingular.

Answer (score 22):

There are many equivalent ways to define supersingularity for an elliptic curve over a characteristic $p$ field.  One of them is that the $p$-torsion of the curve is connected, i.e., it is a purely infinitesimal group scheme of order $p^2$.  As Jonah mentioned, supersingular means very special, and is not a statement about smoothness.  There is a theorem of Deuring that implies the j-invariant of a supersingular elliptic curve always lies in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, and as a consequence, all such curves are defined over a finite degree extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

There are two notions of supersingular prime: one is relative to a fixed elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, and one is absolute.  For any elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$, a prime $p$ is supersingular for $E$ if $E$ has good supersingular reduction at $p$.  Such primes are known to be asymptotically density zero, but infinite in number (by a theorem of Elkies).  Lang and Trotter conjectured that the number of supersingular primes less than $N$ limits to a constant times $\sqrt{N}/\log(N)$ as $N$ gets large.

Supersingular primes in the absolute sense are those primes $p$ for which all supersingular elliptic curves over an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ have $j$-invariant in $\mathbb{F}_p$ instead of just $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$.  These happen to be the primes that divide the order of the monster simple group, and they are also the primes for which the normalizer of $\Gamma_0(p) \in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ acts on the complex upper half plane with a genus zero quotient. For general $p$, this normalizer contains $\Gamma_0(p)$ as an index 2 subgroup, with the nontrivial coset called the "Fricke involution" (a special case of Atkin-Lehner involultion).  There is a standard order 2 representative, taking $z \mapsto -1/pz$.  The quotient curve classifies unordered pairs of elliptic curves with dual degree p isogenies between them.  <strike>I do not know any canonical relations between these characterizations of supersingularity.</strike>

**Edit:** Thanks to Emerton for pointing out the connection.  I'll try to expand on it a bit.  The moduli problem of generalized elliptic curves with $\Gamma_0(p)$-structure has a coarse moduli space that is a smooth irreducible curve away from p, but has mod p fiber given by taking a disjoint union of two copies of $X(1)$ (a genus zero curve) and gluing along supersingular points (this description is more or less in Katz-Mazur, chapter 13).  A geometric point describing an elliptic curve with j-invariant $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ is glued to a geometric point on the other irreducible component describing an elliptic curve with j-invariant $\alpha^p$.  The Fricke involution switches the components, so the quotient of $X_0(p)$ by this involution is a genus zero curve glued to itself at finitely many supersingular points.  The quotient has arithmetic genus zero if and only if all supersingular geometric points are glued to themselves - otherwise, the flat modular deformation to characteristic zero yields a smooth curve of higher genus.  In other words, it is necessary and sufficient that all supersingular geometric points have no Frobenius conjugates, i.e., that the j-invariants of all supersingular curves lie in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

**More Edit:** I should give a more honest reply to Mariano's question, which was originally raised by Ogg in the mid 1970s (and he famously offered a bottle of Jack Daniels to anyone who could solve it).  Half of the question has an answer.  If we combine the results of Borcherds's paper [Monstrous moonshine and monstrous Lie superalgebras](http://math.berkeley.edu/~reb/papers/index.html) with the results of the paper *Modular equations and the genus zero property of moonshine functions* by Cummins and Gannon, we get the following fact:

> Let G be a finite group acting faithfully on a conformal vertex algebra V by conformal symmetries, and suppose V has central charge 24 and character $\operatorname{Tr}(q^{L_0-1}|V) = j(\tau)-744$.  Then for any element $g \in G$, the series $\operatorname{Tr}(gq^{L_0-1}|V)$ is the q-expansion of a modular function that is holomorphic on the upper half plane, invariant under a discrete group $\Gamma \subset PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying $\Gamma \supset \Gamma_0(N)$ for some $N$, and generates the function field of the quotient curve $\Gamma \backslash \mathbf{H}$.  In particular, the quotient curve is genus zero.

The monster simple group arises in this context because I. Frenkel, Lepowsky, and Meurman constructed a conformal vertex algebra satisfying the above hypotheses, whose group of conformal automorphisms is the monster.  The fact given above implies that for each prime p dividing the order of the monster, the quotient $X_0^+(p) = X_0(p)/\langle w_p \rangle$ is genus zero, where $w_p$ is the Fricke involution.  In particular, each prime dividing the order of the monster is necessarily supersingular.

I know some people who would like there to be a conceptual (read: non-enumerative) explanation for why **all** supersingular primes divide the order of the monster.  So far, the best I've heard is that the monster is really big, while there aren't that many supersingular primes.

Comment: What is the reason the primes which divide the order of the monster simple group show up here?

Comment: I don't think a good answer is known.

Comment: Dear Scott,  I'm not sure if this is what you referred to in the last sentence of your answer, but it is not too hard to prove that $p$ is a supersingular prime if and only if $X_0(p)$ mod the A-L involution has genus zero directly from the description of the bad fibre of $X_0(p)$ mod $p$.  (The point being that this description directly involves the s.s. elliptic curves mod p, and the action of Frobenius on their j-invariants.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  Somehow the phrases "AL involution" and "moduli problem at p" never made it into the same part of my brain at the same time.  I will edit the answer when I understand the bad fiber a little better.